# Cannot get List View Item template to display text //Visual studio

Tags: c#

This only displays the text "hello" when I add another control to the list view such as  between </ListView.ItemTemplate> and . What am I doing wrong?

```
<ListView BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Height="266" 
          Width="585" Canvas.Left="33" Canvas.Top="89" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionMode="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Width="103">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="firstRowTextBlock" Text="hello"  FontSize="14" Foreground="White"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: What is the UI framework you use, WPF or Avalonia or maui ... ? ... your code should not display anything because your list is empty, there is no `ListItem` or `ItemsSourse` Binding to this list !

Comment: `Text="hello"` - its hardcoded? have you tried to using data bind directive the good old `<%#`.